# Access environment variables in webpack.js react in kubernetes environment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, kubernetes

This a part of my webpack file.

```
output: {
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../dist/static/"),
    publicPath: `${**process.env.STATIC_URL**}/xxxxxxx/static/`
  }
```

I want to access environment variables set in configmap of kubernetes here. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi, Can You be more specific where "here" is?

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated [`envFrom:` field in the PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#container-v1-core) that allows injecting ConfigMap keys as environment variables (assuming they are "environment safe," so no integers or boolean or non-string values):

```
containers:
- image: whatever
  envFrom:
    configMapRef:
      name: your-configmap-name-goes-here
```

Or, if you just want that **one** key, then there is a similar [`valueFrom:` field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#envvarsource-v1-core) in the `env:` items themselves:

```
containers:
- image: whatever
  env:
  - name: STATIC_URL
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: your-configmap-name-goes-here
        key: whatever-key-holds-the-static-url-value
```

Comment: The values are set in the pod but the app still has it as undefined the build doesn't get this values